# Macbook Air A1466 - WiFi Channel 13

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, macbook-air

We are 5 tenants in a house in the Netherlands and after trying them all we found out that channel 13 was the only one not too crowded to offer us a decent connection. Setting the router on any other channel makes the internet almost unusable for everybody. Problem is that the  cannot detect the WiFi connection whenever it is set on channel 13.

Is there anyway to get a Macbook Air to detect channel 13 on our Wifi router?

Thank you.

Comment: Go into System Information > Wifi and take a look at the supported channels, make sure that 13 is listed.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. And if it is not listed, is there any way to make it available?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on several StackExchanges sites at the same time (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131355/macbook-air-a1466-wifi-channel-13)

Comment: Why not just use 5 GHz WiFi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel 13 isn't allowed in North America (where FCC rules are used). If that laptop was purchased in North America, it probably defaults to FCC mode where it won't try to use channels 12 or 13.

When the card is powered on at boot or wake, it'll do a scan to find local Wi-Fi networks and if the networks it sees are advertising a European country code, it should switch to ETSI mode and start scanning channels 12 and 13 as well. But if none of the APs it can see on the FCC channels advertise a country code, or if one or more are advertising the wrong country code, it might not realize it needs to switch into ETSI mode.

Go to ` > About This Mac > [More Info…] > [System Report…] > Network > Wi-Fi > Interfaces > enX`

…and look at `Locale`, `Country Code`, and `Supported Channels`.

Then scroll down to the list of local wireless networks it sees, and look at the `Channel` and `Country Code` each one is advertising. Ideally they should all be advertising `NL`.